# Closed-form expression for $\log(x) + \log(x^2) + \cdots + \log(x^n)$

Tags: summation

Does anyone know of a closed-form expression for the following?

$$
\log(x) + \log(x^2) + \cdots + \log(x^n)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Well, since $\log(x^a) = a \log(x)$ that's simply

$$\log(x) \sum_{i=1}^n i = \log(x) \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: And if $$x \le 0$$ ?

Comment: @Shadock That question kind of reminds me of $7$th grade where whenever my teacher said something I said "Not for complex numbers!" Then she said "The absolute value is never less than 0", and I started to say it and she said "Yes Matt, even for complex numbers!"

Comment: I'm a chemist lol so I ask the question and if $x \le 0$ ? :P

Comment: Then the $\log$ is not defined. Yes, not even on $\mathbb{C}$ (although it **can** be defined ).

Comment: If you use the principal branch of logarithm, for $x < 0$ you have $\log(x^n) = \pi i + n \log |x|$ if $n$ is odd and $n \log |x|$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $\log(x)+\log(y)=\log(xy)$, $1+2+3+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, $\log(x^k)=k\log(x)$.